# java static map doesn't update in other class

Tags: java, image, static, maps

Hi there and thanks for reading,

I have a Map initialized as follows:

```
    static HashMap<Point, Tile> map = new HashMap<Point, Tile>();
```

a Tile is a small class that holds an image and a function called `addFloor(int tileCode)`:

```
class Tile {

    BufferedImage img;
    int imgHeight, imgWidth;

    public Tile(BufferedImage img) {
        this.img = img;
        imgHeight = img.getHeight();
        imgWidth = img.getWidth();
    }

    public Tile addFloor(int tileCode) {
        BufferedImage newImg = Helper.joinBufferedImageFloor(this.img, Map.buildings.get(tileCode).img);
        Tile newTile = new Tile(newImg);
        return newTile;
    }
}
```

The `addFloor(int tileCode)` function just puts an image obtained by another map via the `tileCode` as key (Map is just another class that holds the map of Tiles and maps of asset images, and also some unimportant functions for now) on top of the Tile image (`this.img`) with an offset.

(Are you still with me or do i need to give more info?)

and now:

```
Tile tileDebug = Map.map.get(new Point(10, 10));
Map.map.replace(new Point(10, 10), Map.map.get(new Point(10, 10)).addFloor(tileCode)); //I've also tried map.put()
tileDebug = Map.map.get(new Point(10, 10)); //MARK 1
panel.repaint();
```

I checked via eclipse debugger and I checked the `addFloor(int tileCode)` function seperated:

-the `addFloor(int tileCode)` function works perfectly. It creates a new image and returns a completely new Tile with the correct image.

-using the debugger I saw that the Tile updated, it changed its image and has another hash now (same as returned by `addFloor(int tileCode)`).

-Currently the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` function has just one call to `drawMap(Graphics2D g2d)` which draws Tile by Tile.

-Since the `map.replace()` call the map hasn't been edited.

```
private void drawMap(Graphics2D g2d) {
    if (map != null) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= 100; y++) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
                Tile currentTile = Map.map.get(new Point(x, y)); //MARK 2
                if (x == 10 && y == 10) {
                    //This line is just so I can add a breakpoint to debug the tile currentTile
                    System.out.println("");
                } //Unimportant from here, just positioning and drawing, that works perfectly
                int dx = 350, dy = 0;
                dx += Main.viewX;
                dy += Main.viewY;
                int posX, posY;
                posX = (int) ((x * 64 + y * -64));
                posY = (int) ((x * 32 + y *  32));

                posX -= currentTile.imgWidth;
                posY -= currentTile.imgHeight;
                g2d.drawImage(currentTile.img, posX + dx, posY + dy, this);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the drawn Tile isn't the old Tile, it isn't the Tile that got returned by `addFloor(int tileCode)`. The drawn Tile is a new one, with its own hash and image. The image that is drawn is the second image passed to `joinBufferedImageFloor(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2)` (the one obtained via the `tileCode` in `addFloor(int tileCode)`.

I followed my entire program from `//MARK 1` to `//MARK 2`, but the map never got explicitly edited but the return value of

```
Map.map.get(new Point(10, 10))
```

changed from the correct Tile (MARK 1) to the third Tile (MARK 2)

Is it because the Map is static? (Note: Only 2 Threads explicitly edit the Map, the Main Thread and a KeyListener Thread, but in this use case this Thread wasn't involved)
Whats wrong here?
Am I getting something wrong about Java Maps?

Any help appreciated thanks in advance

Edit 1min after posting it:
I think I described it a bit confusing here and there so please ask any question that might be unanswered in this description.
On wish I can also provide you with the full Project setup etc...

Edit few Hours after:
Edited the Question according to the how-to-ask section of StackOverflow

Edit for anyone interested the `joinBufferedImageFloor(BufferdImage img1, BufferedImage img2)` function:

```
public static BufferedImage joinBufferedImageFloor(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {
        int offsetX = 16;
        int offsetY = -32;
        int width = img1.getWidth();
        int height = img1.getHeight() - offsetY;
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = newImage.createGraphics();
        Color oldColor = g2.getColor();
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g2.setColor(oldColor);
        g2.drawImage(img1, null, 0, -offsetY);
        g2.drawImage(img2, null, offsetX, 0);
        g2.dispose();
        return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Does the `Point` class that you are using here provide an overridden `hashcode` and `equals`-method? In case you are using `java.awt.Point`, which is mutable, have you ensured that they are never mutated? (e.g. via any of the `translate`, `move` methods etc.)

Comment: Yes it does, it's just the class "java.awt.Point". The Keys are unique and just used to store an X and Y coordinate.

Comment: Ok, note that it is generally a bad idea to use mutable objects as keys in a `Map`. You need to make sure they are never mutated while they are in use as keys, otherwise you may not be able to retrieve them anymore. See the [JavaDocs of Map: ](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) "Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map."

Comment: If replaced the keys with Integers, but no effect. Everything is unchanged. The Value of the (10 | 10) Key is still changed between "//MARK 1" and "//MARK 2"